# Using TikZ to modify List of Figures using etoolbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents, etoolbox

I have successfully used TikZ to modify the table of contents of a TeX document, and cannot quite figure out how to achieve the same effect for the list of figures, list of tables, acknowledgements, etc.  My (simplified) style file looks like:

```
% Style file to get green boxes in TOC.

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% define color
\definecolor{uvmgreen}{rgb}{0,0.35,0.23}

% ToC title with color box.
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname}{
\vspace*{-70pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=12cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{uvmgreen}\Huge\bfseries \contentsname};%
\draw[fill=uvmgreen,draw=uvmgreen] (13.5,-.75) rectangle (10,1);%
\clip (15.5,-.75) rectangle (10,1);
\pgftext[right,x=12cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\bfseries \contentsname};%
\end{tikzpicture}}{}{}
```

and an example report looks like:

```
\documentclass{report}

% import style file
\usepackage{greenBoxTOC}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\chapter{Quantum Harmonic Oscillator}
\section{test section}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{image.png}
\caption{sample caption} \label{fig: first figure}
\end{figure}

\section{test section }
\subsection{test subsection}
\section{test section}
\subsection{test subsection}
\subsection{A test subsection with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\section{test section}


\chapter{Is it a Riemann Integral?} 
\section{test section}
\subsection{test subsection}
\section{test section with a long title spanning more than one line in the table of contents}
\subsection{test subsection}

\end{document}
```

I would really like to be able to add a `\listoffigures` that would use the same green boxes which show up at the top where it says 'List of Figures'.  My (unsuccessful) attempt at this was to add the following to the style file:

```
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\figurename}{
\vspace*{-70pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\pgftext[right,x=12cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{uvmgreen}\Huge\bfseries \figurename};%
\draw[fill=uvmgreen,draw=uvmgreen] (15.5,-.75) rectangle (10,1);%
\clip (15.5,-.75) rectangle (10,1);
\pgftext[right,x=12cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\bfseries \figurename};%
\end{tikzpicture}}{}{}
```

but when I add this, nothing seems to happen.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah!  Indeed.  Thanks for this (and for pointing out the e-mail address).  If you will put that as an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The `\listoffigures` macro does not contain a reference to `\figurename` but to `\listfigurename`. And `\listtablename` for the `\listoftables`.

There are more references to `\contentsname` and `\list*name` in the `\tableofcontents` or the `\listof*s` macro respectively. These are used for the markings when headings are enabled. These should not be changed.

You could also change `\contentsname` or `\listof*` directly, however I advise against it as they could be used somewhere else (e.g. in a heading) which might break everything.

I’d also suggest to introduce a macro, say `\tikzHeader` that produces your green box to separate content from the TeXnics. I also removed the `remember picture` key as I don’t see where or why you want to reference anything in your picture (there isn’t anything to reference anyway).

```
\newcommand*\tikzHeader[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \pgftext[right,x=12cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{uvmgreen}\Huge\bfseries\htStrut\smash{#1}};
  \draw[fill=uvmgreen,draw=uvmgreen] (13.5cm,-.75cm) rectangle (10cm,1cm);
  \clip (15.5cm,-.75cm) rectangle (10cm,1cm);
  \pgftext[right,x=12cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\bfseries\htStrut\smash{#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

I added a `\htStrut` macro defined as

```
\newcommand*\htStrut{\rule{0pt}{.7\baselineskip}}
```

and `\smash` the actual text (which means it has no vertical dimensions for `\pgftext`). (The `g` in "Figure" will throw the vertical placement off otherwise.) If you have `amsmath` loaded, you can just use `\smash[b]{#1}` and drop the `\htStrut`.